# wifi not working after sleep/ suspend

Tags: release-hera, wifi, suspend, hp

wifi not working after sleep/ suspend. the only solution that works for me is to reboot the system. please provide a permanent solution. I am using HP laptop and recently switched to elementary hera from windows 10. any solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

First solution is to type in terminal:

```
sudo -i /bin/systemctl enable wifi-resume.service exit
```

If this will not work, then below you have solution.

Second solution is to create a file:

```
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
```

Paste below this:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "${1}" in
   resume|thaw) 
    nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on;; 
esac
```

Ctrl+o to save, Ctrl+x to exit.

Then type in terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
```

to make the file executable

If this will not work put this into the file mentioned above:

```
#!/bin/bash 
case $1 in
    resume|thaw)
        nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on;; 
esac
```

If it will not work, put this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
case $1 in
    post|resume|thaw) 
        nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on;; 
esac
```